# Use of find in unix on strange file/directory names

Tags: shell-script, tcsh, csh

I'm writing a script which uses find for putting path of directories this is the part of the script:

```
set list = (`find $PATH -type d`)
```

It works fine until the file or directory names aren't named such as:

```
fi@@lename&& or −filename or :−,?!drectoryanem!-
```

These special characters I couldn't handle, I changed the find script to:

```
set list = ("`find $PATH -type d`")
```

but none of these works, when I want to use the path from the list in this next script:

```
foreach i ($list:q)
   foreach file (`find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type f`)
   ....
   end
end
```

it couldn't handle these special file names, so I get many errors like find:

```
−."!filenda no such filename or directory
```

Comment: I couldn't duplicate this behavior on my system. What is your OS and what version of `findutils` do you have?

Comment: my OS version is FreeBSD 3.2  it havent findutils, i use simple find

Comment: Is it a computer archaeology course? Why on earth would anyone teach csh scripting in the 21st century?

Comment: csh/tcsh is a waste of time at this point. There are several better options.

Comment: What should i learn instead of csh/tcsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out

It had to be this way:

```
set subor = ("`find "'"$i"'" -type f -maxdepth 1`")
```

now it ignores everything in the filenames

and in:

```
foreach j ($subor:q)
```

i quoted it this way it ignores the white characters in file names

Answer (score 2):

In order to manage unusual filenames, you need to put quotes (") around them. However, it looks like you're not using `find` in the most efficient manner. One of the key parts of `find` is that it will do things to the files that are selected. So:

```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

will run everything after the -exec on every file that is found, replacing the `{}` with the filename.

Also, something is very strange if you are using FreeBSD 3.2 - it came out in May 1999.

Comment: Yes i know -exec, but in my case i need to count the lines of a file and sum them for each directory, so couldnt find a way how to do it in an exec, thats why i need  always the path for the files and redirect them to wc and count them,

Comment: and FreeBSD 3.2 we use in school, so i need to use it althought its prehystoric